# Permutation of keys inserted into a tree?

Tags: probability, graph-theory, permutations, trees

Give the fraction of permutations of the keys $A $ through $G$ that will, when inserted into an
initially empty tree, produce the same Binary search tree as does
$A$ $E$ $F$ $G$ $B$ $D$ $C$

ANSWER:

**(5 C 2) /7! = 10/5040 = 1/504.**

Anyone has a clue on how we came up with this answer?

[image]

Comment: First you should probably draw the particular tree you get from that insertion order ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm I have it drawn now. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a given binary search tree, the possible insertion sequences that will produce that tree is exactly *every sequence where an internal node comes before all of its descendants in the tree*.

So in this case, the sequence *must* start with `A E`, `F` must come before `G`, and `B`, `D`, `C` occur in that order between themselves.

But we're free to choose how we merge the sublists `F G` and `B C D` to produce the final sequence. Once we have written down `A E`, we can choose any $2$ of the remaining $5$ positions to be `F` and `G`, and the last three then become `B`, `D` and `C`, in that order.

Therefore there are $\binom52=10$ different input sequences that produce your given tree.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the first key in the permutation must be $A$, since that determines the root of the derived tree. The second key will be a child of $A$, so it must be $E$. Similarly, the third key must be one of $B$ and $F$. Let’s take a closer look at the string consisting of the last five keys.

- It must begin with $B$ or $F$.
- $B$ must precede both $C$ and $D$.
- $D$ must precede $C$, as otherwise $C$ would be a child of $B$.
- $F$ must precede $G$.

That boils down to saying that $B,D$, and $C$ must appear in that order, and that $F$ and $G$ must appear in that order, but the strings $BDC$ and $FG$ can be interlaced arbitrarily. Thus, once we decide which two of the last five keys are $F$ and $G$, we’ve completely determined the order of the keys: if the last five keys are, for instance, $??FG?$, then they must be $BDFGC$. There are $\binom52$ ways to choose two of the five positions to be filled by $F$ and $G$, so there are $\binom52$ possible permutations that yield the desired tree.